# How to capture words around regular expression pattern?

Tags: regex, string, swift

I have a String which is :

```
let s : String = "The dog ate the cat."
```

With the following pattern :

```
let p : NSRegularExpression = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\w( )?dog( )?\\w"), options: .CaseInsensitive)
```

My question is : How do I get the words before and after the pattern's occurrence?

This is my current implementation :

```
let t : [NSTextCheckingResults] = p.matchesInString(s, options: [], NSMakeRange(0, NSString(string: s).length))
print(String(t[0].URL!))
```

However this does not return the desired result.

What is wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: Your pattern is current getting `e dog a` is it what you really wants? See it here: https://regex101.com/r/zM6aF2/1

Comment: No it is not. Though that is more information than I had previously. All Xcode shows when I print is: "\\w( )?dog( )?\\w"

Comment: Well I'm not an ios developer. I was sharing my knowledge on the regex only. Don't know if objC needs scaping or not. Though in regex the pattern you would need to get what you ask in your question would be `(.+)\bdog\b(.+)` then you get the capturing groups from it. See this regex working here: https://regex101.com/r/zM6aF2/2

Comment: Looking for how to extract capturing groups I found this link, it may be helpful: http://snipplr.com/view/63340/

Comment: What exactly do you want to capture, "the" and "ate"?

Comment: @CodeDifferent I want to capture "the dog ate" without specifying "the" or "ate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
extension String {
    subscript (range: NSRange) -> String {
        let startIndex = self.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location)
        let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(range.length)

        return self[startIndex..<endIndex]
    }
}

let s = "The dog ate the cat."

let pattern = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(\\w+)?\\s?dog\\s?(\\w+)?", options: [.CaseInsensitive])

let matches = pattern.matchesInString(s, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, s.characters.count))

for m in matches {
    print(s[m.rangeAtIndex(0)])

    let range1 = m.rangeAtIndex(1)
    if range1.location != NSNotFound {
        print("capture group 1:", s[range1])
    }

    let range2 = m.rangeAtIndex(2)
    if range2.location != NSNotFound {
        print("capture group 2:", s[range2])
    }
}
```

The extension to `String` is optional but it makes working with `NSRange` much easier. The 2 capture groups were made optional with `(\\w+)?` so it matches the following strings too:

```
// The dog ate the cat
The dog ate
capture group 1: the
capture group 2: ate

// dog ate my home work
dog ate
capture group 2: ate

// I love my dog
my dog
capture group 1: my

// dog
dog
```

Comment: The regular expression works (huzzah!) Though it seems that the NSTextCheckingResult has no URL property. Any ideas as to why this is the case?

Comment: Checkout [`NSDataDetector`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDataDetector/checkingTypes), a subclass of `NSRegularExpression`. `NSDataDetector` is essentially Apple-provided regular expressions that help you detect some common data (URLs, address, calendar dates, etc.). Anyhow, there's no URL to capture within your sample strings.